# Why isn't my css applying to my next divs?

Tags: html, css

Can someone tell me why I'm able to style the header class but not my MainContent class? Only the Lorum Ipsum text shows up. The maincontent div doesn't show any width, height or color. Thanks for any help!

```css
.header {
    width: 100%;
    height: 90px;
    background-color: blue;
}

.header img {
 height: 80%;
 margin-top: 10px;
 margin-left: 260px;
}﻿

.MainContent {
    width: 100%;
    height: 80%;
    background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<div class="header">
 <img src="img/epic_it.png" alt="epicit logo">
 <nav></nav>
</div>

<div class="MainContent">
 <h1>
 Lorem ipsum
 </h1>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a really strange piece of markup at the end of your `.header img` declaration, which is being considered a `CodeMirror invalid character`, and causing any CSS that follows it to break. If you edit your snippet, you'll see a red circle there, though it is invisible in the snippet preview.

Simply removing that fixes the problem:

```css
.header {
  width: 100%;
  height: 90px;
  background-color: blue;
}

.header img {
  height: 80%;
  margin-top: 10px;
  margin-left: 260px;
}

.MainContent {
  width: 100%;
  height: 80%;
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<div class="header">
  <img src="img/epic_it.png" alt="epicit logo">
</div>

<div class="MainContent">
  <h1>
    Lorem ipsum
  </h1>
</div>
```

Hope this helps! :)

Comment: Thank you so much! This fixed my problem :)

Comment: Glad to hear this solution appears to have worked for you. Once you've confirmed this solution solves your problem, please don't forget to mark the solution as correct by clicking on the grey check below the vote buttons -- this removes it from the 'Unanswered Questions' queue, and awards reputation to both the question asker and question answerer. Of course, in saying that, you are under no obligation to mark my answer (or any other answer) as correct, though it does help to keep things flowing smoothly :)

Comment: img tag needs a closing tag

Comment: @ZohirSalakCeNa - actually, the [**`<img>` tag**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/img) specifically must **not** have a closing tag; it is one of the 15 [**empty elements**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Empty_element) (meaning it cannot contain any child nodes).